# Redshift: Import csv file of large size (~6GB) with comma in the name column

Tags: amazon-redshift

I tried to import a csv file (of size ~6GB) from s3 to redshift with the COPY command:

```
copy test.test_pat_temp from 's3://some_location/large_file.csv'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<Secret_Key>'
DELIMITER AS ','
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL;
```

But got the following error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
>   copy test_qa.test_pat_temp from 's3://some_location/large_file.csv'
>   credentials 'aws_access_...
>
> Amazon Invalid operation: Load into table 'test_pat_temp' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.;
>
> Execution time: 42.34s
>
> 1 statement failed.

The reason for the error in 'stl_load_errors' table is **"Extra column(s) found"**.

I checked the csv file and it had comma (,) in many cells of name column. e.g. Lastname,Firstname.

How do I handle the comma while importing the csv file in redshift? I googled the error and just got the generic answer "handle the commas in the required column". Can anyone give me some details on how to handle the comma?

Comment: Can you post an example line from the CSV file that exhibits the problem?  Are their quotes around the names with commas in them or some other way to figure out how to separate the CSV data into the required columns?

Comment: There are 329 columns and one of the columns is FULL_NAME with value say "Last_name, First_name". The values of the row are separated by comma.

so a row would be something like:
1,2,88,,"Last_name,First_name",Company,,,,stack,overflow,,,, and so on.

Comment: I managed to import the file by simply adding REMOVEQUOTES option:

copy test.test_pat_temp from 's3://some_location/large_file.csv'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<access_key>;aws_secret_access_key=<Secret_Key>'
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL
REMOVEQUOTES;

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 329 columns and one of the columns is FULL_NAME with value say "Last_name, First_name". The values of the row are separated by comma. so a row would be something like: 1,2,88,,"Last_name,First_name",Company,,,,stack,overflow,,,, and so on.

I managed to import the file by simply adding REMOVEQUOTES option:

copy test.test_pat_temp from 's3://some_location/large_file.csv'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key='
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL
REMOVEQUOTES;